# What's the best to prepare to new Developer transition exams

Tags: certification

Just got a mail from Salesforce about transition exam for Developer/Advanced Developer. Any ideas how to best prepare for the exams. Study guide doesn't seems me very useful. Is experience enough or need to study something?

Comment: Yes.. requesting everyone to share the experience once you write the exam..

Comment: Well, if you got the email, it has study guides, outlines, etc. I would say it pretty much answers your questions.....Dev Console, Flows, Process Builder is big in the new exams (so far, final has not been decided yet)